# Azure ARM deployment access a resource from a different subscription when deploying a new resource

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I am using an Azure service principal and C# Azure SDK to deploy this ARM template. The  `publicIPPrefixResourceId` I am passing as a parameter is the ARM Id of the resource that **is in a different subscription** from where I am currently deploying to. However, the service principal has access to both subscriptions. But I get an error saying it was not able to find the `publicIPPrefixResourceId` in the current subscription.

I am wondering is there a way to specify that also includes other subscriptions while looking for a resource? I don't want to use a custom-managed service identity because my service principle has access to both subscriptions.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "publicIpName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "publicIpSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard"
    },
    "publicIPPrefixResourceId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Resource Id of the PublicIpPrefix to create VM VIP"
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "name": "[parameters('publicIpName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('publicIpSku')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
        "publicIPPrefix": {
          "Id": "[parameters('publicIPPrefixResourceId')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

C# Azure SDK that is deploying above ARM template:

```
        var deploymentTask = azure.Deployments.Define(parameters.DeploymentName)
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroupName)
            .WithTemplate(vmTemplate)
            .WithParameters(deploymentParameters)
            .WithMode(DeploymentMode.Incremental)
            .Create();
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is doable, while looking for resource group, you are looking under a specific subscription.
The SDK you are using is our old Azure SDK for .net, I'll suggest that you try our new SDK [Azure.ResourceManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager/1.0.0) and [Azure.ResourceManager.Resource](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources/), the new SDK integrates with the latest [Azure.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity/), you can directly use azure resource identifier to look for resources

```
var client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var resourceGroup = client.GetResourceGroupResource(new Azure.Core.ResourceIdentifier("/subscriptions/<Subscriptionid>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroupname>"));
ArmDeploymentCollection ArmDeploymentCollection = resourceGroup.GetArmDeployments();
        string deploymentName = "myDeployment";
        var input = new ArmDeploymentContent(new ArmDeploymentProperties(ArmDeploymentMode.Incremental)
        {
            TemplateLink = new ArmDeploymentTemplateLink()
            {
                Uri = new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.storage/storage-account-create/azuredeploy.json")
            },
            Parameters = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new JsonObject()
                {
                    {"storageAccountType", new JsonObject()
                        {
                            {"value", "Standard_GRS" }
                        }
                    }
                })
        });
        ArmOperation<ArmDeploymentResource> lro = await ArmDeploymentCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, deploymentName, input);
        ArmDeploymentResource deployment = lro.Value;
```

Or hierarchy look for the resources like below

```
var client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
var subscriptions =client.GetSubscriptions();
foreach(var sub in subscriptions)
{
    Console.WriteLine("SubID:"+sub.Data.DisplayName);
    var rgs = sub.GetResourceGroups();
    foreach(var rg in rgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RgName:"+rg.Data.Name);
        ArmDeploymentCollection ArmDeploymentCollection = rg.GetArmDeployments();
        string deploymentName = "myDeployment";
        var input = new ArmDeploymentContent(new ArmDeploymentProperties(ArmDeploymentMode.Incremental)
        {
            TemplateLink = new ArmDeploymentTemplateLink()
            {
                Uri = new Uri("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/quickstarts/microsoft.storage/storage-account-create/azuredeploy.json")
            },
            Parameters = BinaryData.FromObjectAsJson(new JsonObject()
                {
                    {"storageAccountType", new JsonObject()
                        {
                            {"value", "Standard_GRS" }
                        }
                    }
                })
        });
        ArmOperation<ArmDeploymentResource> lro = await ArmDeploymentCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, deploymentName, input);
        ArmDeploymentResource deployment = lro.Value;

    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

The new version SDK is going to cover more Azure services very soon

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reference a resource the way you are trying to do. There are caveats however:

1. You need to provide the resourceId correctly, for example: `"/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-tmp/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPPrefixes/prefixtemp"` - see also [`resourceId` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid)
2. You cannot reference a public IP prefix in another subscription. This is not a limitation of ARM but rather [of the specific service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/public-ip-address-prefix#limitations).

> all public IP addresses created from the prefix must exist in the same Azure region and subscription as the prefix.

Full "working" example:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Location for all resources."
        }
      },
      "publicIpName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "publicIpSku": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Standard"
      },
      "publicIPPrefixResourceId": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
          "description": "Resource Id of the PublicIpPrefix to create VM VIP"
        },
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-tmp/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPPrefixes/prefixtemp"
      }
    },
    "resources": [
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "ipPrefixInOtherSubscription": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[reference(parameters('publicIPPrefixResourceId'), '2021-08-01').ipPrefix]"
        }
      }
  }
```

If you try to use it like you intended, you get this error:

```json
{
    "code": "ResourceReferenceUsesWrongSubscriptionId",
    "message": "Property publicIPPrefix of resource /subscriptions/11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-temp/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/test can only reference resources in subscription(s) 11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. Value /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/rg-tmp/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPPrefixes/prefixtemp references wrong subscription.",
    "details": []
}
```

And there is no way around that.